# DAutomationHC39M font showing background bar while using with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to use "IDAutomationHC39M Free Version.ttf" font in my PDF file.
The file is being generated using iTextSharp.

The file gets generated but when the PDF is viewed it looks like this: 
[without font as font was not embedded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzF7u.png)
Please see the bar in the middle.

When I embed the font in the PDF document, it looks like this:
[see the bar in the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btepO.jpg)

My code is as follows:

```
Barcode39 barcode39 = new Barcode39();

var barcodeValue = "";

// ID Automation Font

string file = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~//fonts//IDAutomationHC39M Free Version.ttf");

var baseFnt = BaseFont.CreateFont(file, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

document.Open();
barcodeValue = "10000007300045487901"; // Code in the sample pdf
barcode39.Code = barcodeValue;

var BarCodeHeight= float.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BarCodeHeight"]);
var BarCodeX     = float.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BarCodeX"]);
var BarCodeLocX  = float.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BarCodeLocX"]);
var BarCodeLocY  = float.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BarCodeLocY"]);
var BarCodeInk   = float.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BarCodeInk"]);
var BarCodeArLocX= float.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BarCodeArLocX"]);
var BarCodeArLocY= float.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BarCodeArLocY"]);

barcode39.GuardBars = true;
barcode39.ChecksumText = true;
barcode39.BarHeight = BarCodeHeight;
barcode39.X = BarCodeX;
//barcode39.InkSpreading = BarCodeInk; // Comment out this for ID Automation Font
//barcode39.StartStopText = false;

barcode39.Font = baseFnt; // ID Automation Font

iTextSharp.text.Image img2 = barcode39.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
```